# jQuery: function in dynamic generated list item doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

I build a function to display a value in a HTML element for a

```
<input type="range">
```

object.

My function works fine:

```
var rangeValues = { "50": "Fifty" , "100": "Hundred" , "...": "..." };

  $(function Skilllevel() {
    $('#rangeText').text(rangeValues[$('#rangeInput').val()]);
    $('#rangeInput').on('input change', function ()
        {
        $('#rangeText').text(rangeValues[$(this).val()]);
        });
  });
```

See example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dzzxL4m/)

My problem now is the following:
I putted the function `Skilllevel()` into a `$.each(result, function` and into it, it doesn't work, because every entry from my second JSON file `var urlBewerbungID = "json.php";` generated one **separate** list element in `$("#ergebnisSkill").append(`

The second JSON looks very simple, like this:

```
[
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3"
]
```

My complete function:

```js
//Skills selektieren

var rangeValues = {
  "0": "Keine",
  "33": "Anfänger",
  "66": "Fortgeschritten",
  "99": "Profi"
};

//Abfrage, welche Stelle gewählt wurde
$('#bewerbungID').on('change', function() {
  var bewerbungID = ($('#bewerbungID').val());
  console.log("BewerbungsID gewählt: " + bewerbungID);

  //Zuerst das #HTML Element leeren
  $("#ergebnisSkill").empty();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var urlBewerbungID = "json.php";
    $.getJSON(urlBewerbungID, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        var skill = field;

        //Skill liste erstellen
        $(function Skilllevel() {
          $('#rangeText').text(rangeValues[$('#rangeInput').val()]);
          $('#rangeInput').on('input change', function() {
            $('#rangeText').text(rangeValues[$(this).val()]);
          });
        });

        //Jetzt HTML Element neu befüllen
        $("#ergebnisSkill").append(

          '<li>' +
          '<div class="item-content">' +
          '<div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">star</i></div>' +
          '<div class="item-inner">' +
          '<div class="item-title label">' + skill + '<br> <span id="rangeText"></span></div>' +
          '<div class="item-input">' +
          '<div class="range-slider">' +
          '<input type="range" id="rangeInput" min="0" max="99" value="0" step="33">' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</li>'

        );

      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inside out.

- You need document.ready to wrap the event handlers.
- Use class instead of IDs, IDs need to be unique
- use delegation - currently you have a function per result which does not work.
- You need the skills functionality assigned to each result but delegated - see how a click on the `ergebnisSkill` will be captured by the rangeInput:

  ```js
  //Skills selektieren
  var rangeValues = {
    "0": "Keine",
    "33": "Anfänger",
    "66": "Fortgeschritten",
    "99": "Profi"
  };


  $(document).ready(function() {

    //Skill liste erstellen

    $("#ergebnisSkill").on('input change', ".rangeInput", function() { // delegation
      $(this).closest("item-inner") // a parent div
        .find('.rangeText') // the input field
        .text(rangeValues[$(this).val()]);
    });

    //Abfrage, welche Stelle gewählt wurde
    $('#bewerbungID').on('change', function() {
      var bewerbungID = ($('#bewerbungID').val());
      console.log("BewerbungsID gewählt: " + bewerbungID);

      //Zuerst das #HTML Element leeren
      $("#ergebnisSkill").empty();

      var urlBewerbungID = "json.php";
      $.getJSON(urlBewerbungID, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
          var skill = field;


          //Jetzt HTML Element neu befüllen
          $("#ergebnisSkill").append(

            '<li>' +
            '<div class="item-content">' +
            '  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">star</i></div>' +
            '  <div class="item-inner">' +
            '    <div class="item-title label">' + skill + '<br> <span class="rangeText"></span></div>' +
            '    <div class="item-input">' +
            '      <div class="range-slider">' +
            '        <input type="range" class="rangeInput" min="0" max="99" value="0" step="33">' +
            '      </div>' +
            '    </div>' +
            '  </div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</li>'

          );
        });
      });
    });
  });
  ```